# Searchview on Toolbar with multiple fragment inside view pager

Tags: android

I have a main activity in which have a Tool bar with search view and also using View Pager with multiple fragment. Now I want to use search view with vary fragment with vary list view response. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Make searchView `public static` in MainActivty and use `MainActivity.searchView` in each fragment